# Hadoop Datanode workers is not connecting to my master:Problem connecting to server: master:9000

Tags: hadoop

```
RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 2023-02-24 11:29:55,841 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: master:9000
```

I have installed hadoop following these step:

After moving all the files to datanode

```
$ hdfs namenode -format 
$ start-dfs.sh
```

Namenode is working:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm96V.png)

Datanode is also working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhFg6.png)

But I have this error: When I check the log file I have this issue of connection to datanode!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WP17.png)

Comment: This is just a DNS error. Is your server actually named `master`? Have you tried to change values files to use IP addresses? Otherwise, you need to fix values in the router or at least `/etc/hosts`. This has nothing to do with Hadoop, really

Comment: hello @OneCricketeer thank you for reply. It work know! The problem was firewalld.          I stopped the firewald "systemctl stop firewalld"  and work now thk.

Comment: That's not really recommended for production setup, but glad to hear it. Instead, you'd add allow rules for the necessary ports